# spring security + webflux + react

Tags: reactjs, spring-security, spring-webflux

I have a project with react and spring security with weblux but custom login page is not submitting properly. After application starting I receive browser authentication window. In postman evertyhing is ok on backend side. What can be a reason? Is in jsx onSubmit method needed? Based on this article https://www.sudoinit5.com/post/spring-reactive-auth-forms/ is not needed. It is my code

```
SecutiryConfig.java

    @EnableWebFluxSecurity
    public class SecurityConfig {
        @Bean
        public SecurityWebFilterChain securityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {

        return http
                .csrf().disable()
                .cors()
                .and()
                .authorizeExchange()
                    .pathMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                    .pathMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/admin/**").authenticated()
                    .anyExchange().authenticated()

                .and()
                    .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/login")
                .and()
                .httpBasic()
                .and()
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public MapReactiveUserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        UserDetails admin = User.builder()
                .username("admin")
                .password("{noop}admin")
                .roles("ADMIN")
                .build();
        return new MapReactiveUserDetailsService(admin);
    }
}
```

Below my react Login page

```
Login.jsx

Class Login extends React.Component {

    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);

        this.state = {
            user: '',
            password: '',
            hasLoginFailed: false,
            showSuccessMessage: false
        };

        this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
    }

    onChange(e){
        this.setState({
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value
        });
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <>
                <div className="content">
                    <Container>
                        <Row>
                            <Col md={{ span: 4, offset: 4 }} className="text-center">

                                <Card border="dark">
                                    <Card.Header as="h3" className="text-center">Login</Card.Header>
                                    <Card.Body>
                                        <Form id="login-form"
                                              action="/login"
                                              method="post">
                                            <Form.Group controlId="formUsername">
                                                <Form.Control type="text" name="user" onChange={this.onChange} placeholder="Username" />
                                            </Form.Group>

                                            <Form.Group controlId="formPassword">
                                                <Form.Control type="password" name="password" onChange={this.onChange} placeholder="Password" />
                                            </Form.Group>
                                            <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>
                                            <ButtonToolbar size="lg">
                                                <Button type="submit" variant="dark" block> Submit </Button>
                                            </ButtonToolbar>

                                        </Form>
                                    </Card.Body>
                                </Card>
                            </Col>
                        </Row>
                    </Container>
                </div>
            </>
        );
    }

}
```

In WebConfig I have the code as below:

```
@Bean
public RouterFunction<?> routerFunction(@Value("classpath:/resources/index.html") Resource html) {
    return RouterFunctions.route()

            .POST("/login", request -> ok().render("login-form", request.exchange().getAttributes()))
}
```

Comment: please run it in a browser and enter the development tools and check what your request looks like and the actual response, with status code and body, headers etc. etc. then your `After submit I receive an answer CANNOT POST /login`

Comment: i receive an answer Request URL: http://localhost:3000/login
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 404 Not Found

Comment: there is your answer 404, which means that localhost:3000/login does not exist. You backend is probably running per default on localhost:8080 and not port 3000. When you run react, it gets started on a node server that is on port 3000. While your Spring backend server is running per default on port 8080

Comment: yes, I know, but what if I have react turned on from npm (3000) and backend (8080) in what way I can check security? Only with build?

Comment: you have two choices, either serve the react application from your spring application. So you build your react application and then copy over the statically generated files from the build, to your spring app and serve it from the spring app. Or if you are in production running your react app seperatly and your spring app seperatly, you need to instead do your post against the correct address. The react app per default will set the host to localhost:3000. Since i have no idea how this is run in prod/your env i cant give you an answer

Comment: you can read this about setting up proxys in react app https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development

Comment: Ok, I did it. But now I have browser window for user and password. Method formlogin in SecurityConfig is not switching off browser authentication?

Comment: @JJ36, Were you able to make it work?  My requirement also exactly same. Running react and Spring app separately. But not sure how to make the form based auth work with react.